# Implement a post insert hook to increment a value from a different entity

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have a `posts` entity

```ts
@Entity('posts')
class PostEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id: number;

  @Column()
  public title: string;

  @Column()
  content: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, (user) => user.posts)
  author: number;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;
}

export default PostEntity;
```

which is connected to `users` entity

```ts
@Entity('users')
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id: number;

  @Column()
  public name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => PostEntity, (posts) => posts.author)
  posts: PostEntity[];

  @Column({
    type: 'int',
    default: 0
  })
  public post_count: number;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;
}

export default UserEntity;
```

I want to implement a function in `posts` which increments the value of `post_count` in `users` after a post is inserted corresponding to the user's id. I have looked at many examples but they use functions which are deprecated in the current nestjs version. I also tried injecting user repository in posts service

```ts
@Injectable()
export class PostsService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(PostEntity) private readonly postsRepository: Repository < Posts > ,
    private userRepository: Repository < User > ,
  ) {}
}
```

but it gives me error `Nest can't resolve dependencies of the PostsService (PostEntityRepository, ?). Please make sure that the argument Repository at index [1] is available in the PostsModule context.`

How can i implement this?

Comment: you'll need to use `@InjectRepository(UserEntity)` on the second paramater of `PostService`'s `constructor` like you did for the first one as well

Comment: @MicaelLevi `Argument of type 'typeof UserEntity' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.` this is what im getting

Comment: When you inject it into service you have to include it in the module.
Also, I  would recommend you to use a `trigger`, because it would be better and more performant.
The number of posts you can always find when you get users because of user. posts.length => gives number of posts

Comment: @MuhametSmaili i didnt wanted to use length() function due to an overhead. Keeping postcounts ready in the table gives it directly. And i have imported `UsersEntity` in `posts.module.ts`. `@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([PostEntity, UserEntity]), UsersModule],
  providers: [PostsService, UserService],
  controllers: [PostsController],
  exports: [PostsService],`